# How to enable runtime commands to C app without using a reader thread?

Tags: c, stdin

I want to implement a C application with the following structure:

```
int main()
{
    initSystem();

    while (1)
    {
        //do something
    }

    deinitSystem();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So what happens when the software is executed is that it enters in the `while(1)` loop and don't get out, doing it stuff normally. But the problem is that, if I want to stop the application, I need it to call `deinitSystem()` before closing, so just killing the application with a Ctrl+C on Terminal or a `killall myprogram` doesn't work; I need to send a command to it saying "hey, time to stop", breaking the while loop and running `deinitSystem`.

The normal way I would do that is by putting a keyboard reader in a part of the loop so if the reader reads the exit command, it breaks the loop. But that would have to be a non-blocking keyboard reader and I couldn't find any valid way for doing this in C + Linux. The only way I found to do it was to create a thread only to read this exit command from Keyboard, breaking the while loop with a flag, but I disliked this solution; I would like to know if there is another way of implementing this without having to use a thread just for reading the keyboard.

Comment: The traditional way is to catch `SIGINT` and set your `while` loop flag in the handler. That way you can quit with `Ctrl+C` and still call your `deinitSystem()`, there's no need to have a separate thread for it.

Comment: Then you might need to either handle the kill-signal, or to add some way of exit the loop.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths it worked for what I wanted. Thanks! (You may add it as an answer)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg for my case, a call to `exit(EXIT_SUCESS)` is enough. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way is (preferably using `sigaction()`) to establish a signal handler for `SIGINT`, and possibly other signals. You can have a flag for your `while` loop, such as:

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t keep_looping = true;
```

and in your handler:

```
void handler(int signum) {
    keep_looping = false;
}
```

Then in your main program, just loop:

```
while ( keep_looping ) { ...
```

which will keep going until the program catches `SIGINT`, sets the flag, and then your loop will end, at which point you can call `deinitSystem()` or anything else, and exit normally.